# Destroy a wall c# unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a temp to destroy a wall wen the player is on trigger enter but the trigger it will only activate wen the player have place the cube in the respective place and the if the cube is in the correct place than the wall it will be destroyed..

this is my script for the trigger of the cube
in this script it will destroy the cube and the trigger cube 
and set the variable of the wall hp to 0

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class triggerwall : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] objects;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    destroywall.hp -= 4;
    Debug.Log ("hp wall"+destroywall.hp);
    Destroy (gameObject);
    Debug.Log ("game object"+gameObject);
    Destroy (other.gameObject);
    Debug.Log ("other game object"+other.gameObject);
    //Destroy (gameObject);
    //Destroy (other.gameObject);



}

// Finally, this line destroys the gameObject the player collided with.
//Destroy(other.gameObject);

}
```

and then the wall script
it will compare the variable hp and hpx if is == the destroy the wall

well i am not experienced c# developer i have try in multiple forms but i destroy every thing but not the wall
this is the wall script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class destroywall : MonoBehaviour
{
                    //Alternate sprite to display after Wall has been attacked by player.
    public static int hp = 4;                          //hit points for the wall.
    public static int hpx = 0;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {  
    if(hp == hpx) {
        Debug.Log (other.gameObject.tag);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);



            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the hp static? and why are you using a variable to store 0?

Comment: well i dont know that much from c# and i have find that solution to compare  the two variables to compare them

Comment: Then do keep in mind, that you can only have 1 instance of the wall. As they will all share the same hp. Atleast as long as you keep it static.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved the script By Change the wall script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class destroywall : MonoBehaviour
{
                    //Alternate sprite to display after Wall has been attacked by player.
    public static int hp = 4;                          //hit points for the wall.
    public static int hpx = 0;

void  OnTriggerEnter (  Collider other   ){
    if (other.tag == "destroywall") {
        if (hp == hpx) {
            Destroy (other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: This is C# just if some one need to know, and tanks to all for the help